# How to avoid anonymous type after executing LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, type-conversion

I need to set LINQ query results to double array.
After executing the next statement I get anonymous types, and I can't convert the Array to double type. How can I do that?
Code:

```
var rls = context.Test
    .GroupBy(cont => new
    {
        wd = System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", cont.datetime),
        hh = System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DatePart("hour", cont.datetime)
    })
    .Select(rs => new
        {
            rs.Key.wd,
            rs.Key.hh,
            count = rs.Count()
        }).Where(rs => rs.hh != null & rs.wd !=null).ToArray();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you want to convert the array to a double?

Comment: Well what do you *want* the result to be? You've got three fields in your anonymous type - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The result should be any array without anonymos types - double or integer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this `Select` method is returning an anonymous type and this becomes the return type of the query after that point

```
.Select(rs => new
    {
        rs.Key.wd,
        rs.Key.hh,
        count = rs.Count()
    })
```

In order to return another type you will need another `Select` statement to create a new value to return in the pipeline.  The question mentions getting a `double` return but it's unclear which value you want to be the `double` value.  If you just wanted to return say the `wd` parameter then you could do the following

```
.Where(rs => rs.hh != null & rs.wd !=null)
.Select(x => x.wd)
.ToArray();
```

Comment: I need to return both **wd** and **hh** values as double. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. I obtain _int?_ values as the result of LINQ query.